# I want to add number in variable but it is concatenated instead

Tags: javascript

i think its a bug in javascript.

```
function RaviSendURL(p,w,h) {
var hh = (h + 10);
alert (hh);   //must display 110 but it shows 10010
}
RaviSendURL(asdasd,200,100)
```

Comment: parseInt() - not bug. :)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you think there's a bug in the language, you're probably wrong

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/RnDKU/

Comment: Rather than adding the answer to the text of the question itself, please accept an answer below, or add your own solution as a new answer. This makes it clearer for others that will view this question in the future, and allows your answer to be voted up/down and compared to other answers that may be given. You can also accept your own answer if it's the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be passing a string as the third argument to `RaviSendURL`, when you want to be passing a number. If you have the string '100' you can convert it into a number using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Don't forget to specify that your number is in base 10 with the second argument to parseInt.

Example:

```
function add10(x){
    return x + 10;
}

add10('100'); // '10010'
add10(100);   // 110

parseInt('100', 10); // 100
add10(parseInt('100', 10)); // 110
```

If you want the function to accept strings then you can move the parseInt into the function:

```
function add10(x){
    return parseInt(x, 10) + 10;
}

add10('100'); // 110
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hh = (h*1 + 10);
```